# Randomly sum rows

Tags: sql

I would like to randomly insert in a new temp_table the records from the Initial Table below, grouping them by a new PO number (1234-1, 1234-2,etc..) where each group sum(TKG) is <20 and sum(TVOL) is <0.1

```
INITIAL TABLE 

lineID  PO  Item    QTY Weight  Volume  T.KG    T.VOL
1   1234    ABCD    12  0.40    0.0030  4.80    0.036
2   1234    EFGH    8   0.39    0.0050  3.12    0.040
3   1234    IJKL    5   0.48    0.0070  2.40    0.035
4   1234    MNOP    8   0.69    0.0040  5.53    0.032
5   1234    QRST    9   0.58    0.0025  5.22    0.023
6   1234    UVWX    7   0.87    0.0087  6.09    0.061
7   1234    YZAB    10  0.71    0.0064  7.10    0.064
8   1234    CDEF    6   0.69    0.0054  4.14    0.032
9   1234    GHIJ    7   0.65    0.0036  4.55    0.025
10  1234    KLMN    9   0.67    0.0040  6.03    0.036

NEW Temp_Table should look like:

LineID  PO  Item    QTY Weight  Volume  T.KG    T.VOL
1   1234-1  ABCD    12  0.40    0.0030  4.80    0.036
2   1234-1  EFGH    8   0.39    0.0050  3.12    0.040
5   1234-1  QRST    9   0.58    0.0025  5.22    0.023
3   1234-2  IJKL    5   0.48    0.0070  2.40    0.035
4   1234-2  MNOP    8   0.69    0.0040  5.53    0.032
8   1234-2  CDEF    6   0.69    0.0054  4.14    0.032
6   1234-3  UVWX    7   0.87    0.0087  6.09    0.061
10  1234-3  KLMN    9   0.67    0.0040  6.03    0.036
9   1234-4  GHIJ    7   0.65    0.0036  4.55    0.025
7   1234-4  YZAB    10  0.71    0.0064  7.10    0.064
```

I can't figure out how to code this...

Comment: I dont understand clearly what is needed, what is the logic that the three first rows in the new temp_table has PO 1234-1 then the three next 1234-2, two next rows 1234-3 ect...

Comment: If it's homework, I think they're trying to get you to use a cartesian join....

Comment: If you google "bin packing sql server" you should get some relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a job for a cursor.

The algorithm could basically be like this:

- Collect the rows from the initial table one by one, accumulating `sum(TKG)` and `sum(TVOL)`:

  - pick out the rows into the temp while the conditions are still met (omit those that exceed either sum);
  - use lineID as the order;
  - iterate up to the end of the list.
- Upon hitting the end of the table call it a group, then start all over again, omitting the rows that have already been collected into the temp.
- Continue while there still are rows not collected.

But I'm too lazy at the moment to give out the actual code, besides it's a homework, and cursors hate me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the 1234-1, 1234-2, etc is to break the records into groups that represent a carton. If the order has 100 line items, I may need n cartons (n groups) to pack all the items.